# How to output text result in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

In an android website, I found an article about a widget similar to a drop-down list for selecting items. (Following is the link to the site; and it shows all the codes).

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

It uses the following code to display a message once you have selected a planet.

`Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Planet is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

But this message "Planet is Selected" is only going to display for about 3 seconds and then it disappears. Can you please tell me how can I make the message stay on the screen for a longer time. Or how can I output the "Planet is Selected" message as a text layout in to the screen(So that it will stay on the screen permanently till I select another item from the list)? How can I use `addView(tv)` instead of `setContentView(tv)` Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
   {                   
       if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Mars"))
       {      TextView tv = new TextView(HelloSpinner.this); 
              tv.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() + "Planet is Selected");
              setContentView(tv); //How can I use addView(tv); here?
              //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Planet Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   }

   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) 
   {
         // Do nothing.
   } }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to stay permanently on the screen, why not use a `TextView` and set your value to that instead of a Toast.

If you have any problems with not being able to use TextView, ie undefined. You should take a look at the [textview documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#ui), as it is very well described there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the new TextView(this); parts gives me the following error. `The constructor TextView(HelloSpinner.MyOnItemSelectedListener) is undefined` Can you please tell me how can I correct that. I have `TextView` in my program as shown in the PolamReddyRajaReddy's post above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener   {

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)  {                   

     TextView tv = new TextView(this);
     tv.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()); 
  }
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent)  {
     // Do nothing.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. But the `new TextView(this);` parts gives me the following error. `The constructor TextView(HelloSpinner.MyOnItemSelectedListener) is undefined` Can you please tell me how can I correct that. Thanks.

Comment: use Context instead of this.. Context ctx = getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 0):

third parameter `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` is time. so you can set any integer value ( not sure second or millisecond) ,. then on specific event call toast.hide() ;
toast is good choice for show message for some times only . so use textView if possible

create TextView with activity context :

```
TextView tv = new TextView(ActrivityName.this)
```

else if not an activity

```
TextView tv = new TextView(parent.getContext())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I tried changing it to an integer value. but the it still only stays on for 3 seconds. `Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Planet Selected", 999999).show();`

Comment: `TextView tv = new TextView(ActrivityName.this)`
 It works well and stays on the screen. but I can't go back to my list to choose another planet. since `setContentView(tv);` will just display my message "Planet is Selected" in to the screen and nothing else.

Comment: so don't use setContentView(tv) use addView(tv);

Comment: please search and read little bit before asking . these are absolutely basic things